# How to return the output of a recursive function in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, recursion, lisp, clojure

I'm new to functional languages and clojure, so please bear with me...

I'm trying to construct a list of functions, with either random parameters or constants. The function that constructs the list of functions is already working, though it doesn't return the function itself. I verified this using println.

(edit: Okay, it isn't working correctly yet after all)

**(edit: Now it's working, but it cannot be "eval"-ed. it seems I need to recur at least two times, to ensure there are at least two children nodes. Is this possible?)**

Here is the snippet:

```
(def operations (list #(- %1 %2) #(+ %1 %2) #(* %1 %2) #(/ %1 %2)))
(def parameters (list \u \v \w \x \y \z))
(def parameterlistcount 6)
(def paramcount 2)
(def opcount 4)

(defn generate-function


([] (generate-function 2 4 0.5 0.6 () parameters))
  ([pc maxdepth fp pp function-list params]
     (if (and (pos? maxdepth) (< (rand) fp))
       (let [function-list
             (conj function-list
                    (nth operations
                         (rand-int (count operations))))]
         (recur pc (dec maxdepth) fp pp function-list params))
       (if (and (< (rand) pp) (pos? pc))
         (let [ params (pop parameters)
        function-list
               (conj function-list
                      (nth params
                         (rand-int (count params))))]
       (if (contains? (set operations) (last function-list) )
          (recur (dec pc) maxdepth fp pp function-list params)
          nil))
         (let [function-list
               (conj function-list
                      (rand-int 100))]
           (if (or (pos? maxdepth) (pos? pc))
          (if (contains? (set operations) (last function-list) )
        (recur pc maxdepth fp pp function-list params)
        nil)
          function-list))))))
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my shot at rewriting your function (see comments below):

```
(defn generate-function
  ([] (generate-function 2 4 0.5 0.6 ()))
  ([pc maxdepth fp pp function-list]
     (if (and (pos? maxdepth) (< (rand) fp))
       (let [function-list
             (conj function-list
                   {:op
                    (nth operations
                         (rand-int (count operations)))})]
         (recur pc (dec maxdepth) fp pp function-list))
       (if (and (< (rand) pp) (pos? pc))
         (let [function-list
               (conj function-list
                     {:param
                      (nth parameters
                           (rand-int (count parameters)))})]
           (recur (dec pc) maxdepth fp pp function-list))
         (let [function-list
               (conj function-list
                     {:const
                      (rand-int 100)})]
           (if (or (pos? maxdepth) (pos? pc))
             (recur pc maxdepth fp pp function-list)
             function-list))))))
```

And some examples of use from my REPL...

```
user> (generate-function)
({:const 63} {:op #<user$fn__4557 user$fn__4557@6cbb2d>} {:const 77} {:param \w} {:op #<user$fn__4559 user$fn__4559@8e68bd>} {:const 3} {:param \v} {:const 1} {:const 8} {:op #<user$fn__4559 user$fn__4559@8e68bd>} {:op #<user$fn__4555 user$fn__4555@6f0962>})
user> (generate-function)
({:const 27} {:param \y} {:param \v} {:op #<user$fn__4561 user$fn__4561@10463c3>} {:op #<user$fn__4561 user$fn__4561@10463c3>} {:op #<user$fn__4561 user$fn__4561@10463c3>} {:op #<user$fn__4561 user$fn__4561@10463c3>} {:const 61})
```

A couple of things to keep in mind, in pretty random order:

1. I used `recur` in the above to avoid consuming stack in the recursive self-calls. However, you have this `dotimes` statement which makes me wonder if you might be interested in constructing a bunch of `function-list`s in parallel with one `generate-function` call. If so, tail-recursion with `recur` might not be an option with simplistic code like this, so you could either settle for the regular self-calls (but do consider the possibility of hitting the recursion limit; if you're positive that you'll only generate smallish functions and this won't be a problem, go ahead with the self-calls) or investigate continuation-passing style and rewrite your function in that style.
2. The `(do (dec pc) ...)` thing in your code does nothing to the value of `pc` in the next recursive call, or indeed to its current value. Local variables (or locals, as they are most often called in the community) in Clojure are immutable; this includes function parameters. If you want to pass along a decremented `pc` to some function, you'll have to do just that, like you did with `maxdepth` in an earlier branch of your code.
3. I renamed your function to `generate-function`, because camel case in function names is quite unusual in Clojure land. Also, I renamed the parameter which you called `function` to `function-list` (so maybe I should have used a name like `generate-function-list` for the function... hm), because that's what it is for now.
4. Note that there's no point to keeping a separate `opcount` Var around; Clojure's persistent lists (as created by the `list` function) carry their count around, so `(count some-list)` is a constant-time operation (and very fast). Also, it would be idiomatic to use vectors for `operations` and `parameters` (and you can switch to vectors without changing anything in the rest of the code!). E.g. `[\u \v \w \x \y \z]`.
5. In Clojure 1.2, you'll be able to use `(rand-nth coll)` for `(nth coll (rand-int (count coll)))`.
6. If you want to generate actual Clojure functions from trees of items representing ops, params and constants, you'll want to use `eval`. That's discouraged in most scenarios, but not for evolutionary programming and similar stuff where it's the only way to go.
7. Personally, I'd use a different format of the op/param/constant maps: something like `{:category foo, :content bar}` where `foo` is `:op`, `:param` or `:const` and `bar` is something appropriate in connection to any given `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is a better idea in Clojure to use (recur ...) for your recursive functions. From the docs: "Note that recur is the only non-stack-consuming looping construct in Clojure." [link](http://clojure.org/special_forms#recur)

One other thing to note is that you might want to call the randomizer outside the recursive function, so you can define the stop-condition inside the function.

So like this:

```
(let [n (rand-int 10)] 
  (println "Let's define f with n =" n)
  (defn f [x] 
    (if (> x n) 
      "result" 
      (do (println x) 
          (recur (inc x))))))
```

It prints:

```
Let's define f with n = 4

user> (f 0)
0
1
2
3
4
"result"
```

where 4 is of course a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 10 (exclusive).

Comment: im thankful for the suggestions you have given me, but I think I should have let you guys know my intention.

My goal is to create a function, to be used as population in a genetic programming problem.

@Michal - I can't understand how I could (eval) this...
@Michiel - I see.

Answer (score 1):

So okay, I discovered I was going about this the wrong way.
A recursive definition of a tree is non other than defining vertices, and trying to tie everything with it. So, I came up with this, in less than 15 minutes. >_<

```
(defn generate-branch
"Generate branches for tree"
  ([] (generate-branch 0.6 () (list \x \y \z)))
  ([pp branch params]
      (loop [branch
        (conj branch (nth operations (rand-int (count operations))))]
    (if (= (count branch) 3)
      branch
      (if (and (< (rand) pp))
        (recur (conj branch (nth params (rand-int (count params)))))
        (recur (conj branch (rand-int 100))))))))

(defn build-vertex
"Generates a vertex from branches"
  []
  (let [vertex (list (nth operations (rand-int (count operations))))]
    (conj vertex (take 5 (repeatedly generate-branch)))))
```

THANKS EVERYONE!